# How to unit-test for failed file deletion?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, code-coverage, travis-ci

I have an `os.remove()` in my code that sometimes, when ran locally, fails due to `OSError 13 - Permission Denied` - thus I've set up a `try-except`. My automated testing (Travis CI) is ran on Linux VM instances, so I don't know how to make `os.remove` fail there for sake of coverage.

What are my options - how do I force the `except` block to execute? Alternatively, how do I delete-protect a file with Python?

---

*Note*: Removing it in the test code before calling the test method isn't an option; the method itself fetches files to be removed:

```py
from pathlib import Path

paths = [str(x) for x in Path("directory/").iterdir() if 'abc' in x.stem]
if len(paths) > 0:  # if files are removed beforehand, len(paths) == 0
    try:
        [os.remove(p) for p in paths]
    except:
        pass  # stuff here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unittest.mock.patch` to patch `os.remove` and specify `OSError` as a `side_effect`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

...

with patch('os.remove') as mock_remove:
    mock_remove.side_effect = OSError('Permission Denied')
    try:
        [os.remove(p) for p in paths]
    except OSError as e:
        pass # handle error here
```